# Can the console interact with the Network panel?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I know that you can inspect requests in Chrome DevTool's "Network" tab, and store JSON responses as global variables. I was wondering if there is any way to access requests visible in the "Network" tab from the console?

For instance, if I want to programatically pull data from a specific request, is there a way to do so? Think something like `Chrome.Network.AllRequests` where `AllRequests` is an array or object containing the requests logged in the "Network" tab.

Comment: I don't think there is any way to programmatically interact with the data in the network tab.  But depending on what you're trying to do, you might have options.  

For example, you can export the data from the network tab, e.g. as a HAR or to your clipboard.  Or you can view stats about the requests (but not the content of the responses) via performance.getEntires

Do you have more info about what you're trying to do?

Comment: I'm looking to copy JSON data from a GET request, and mutate it into a more readable format, with just the info I want to review. The website doesn't offer an easy way to copy/reformat data from the page, and I don't want to hammer their servers with additional requests for the data since it's already been delivered (and could be accessed via the network tab)